# What are the uses of a "Empty Project"

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am using VS2010, When you create a new project, you can choose from ConsoleApplication, WindowsFormsApplication, WindowsService, etc. There's also Empty Project.

The empty project contains a reference folder without any references. What is the use of this Empty Project? Is it use for any test?

Comment: No problem, figured since you had you answer I could make everything a bit clearer and easy to find with search ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The “empty project” is used when you wish to create a project that does not have any files or reference automatically added to it.

Sometimes visual studio concept of being helpful is not what you want, and you just wish to be able to define a project to include **only** what you **decide** to put in it.  This is not directly related to using a project for tests, but may be helpful when you are using a test framework that is not supported by any of the project templates.